# Flatten an array of objects and strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array of objects like this:

```
const arr  = [  {
        realEstateBasicInfoResDto: {
            type: "Detached house",
            kind: "Class01"
        },
        assetId: "1",
        realEstateAddressInfoResDto: {
            county: null,
            municipality: null,
            municipalitySection: null,
            address: "Attica, N. Ionia, Iolkou",
            addrNumberFrom: 8,
            addrNumberTo: 0,
            addrLetterFrom: null,
            addrLetterTo: null,
            addressSec: null,
            addrSecLetterFrom: null,
            addrSecLetterTo: null,
            addrSecNumberFrom: 0,
            addrSecNumberTo: 0,
            postalCode: "1"
        },
        realEstateEstimationValuesResDtos: [ ]
    },

    {
        realEstateBasicInfoResDto: {
            type: "Detached house",
            kind: "Class01"
        },
        assetId: "11",
        realEstateAddressInfoResDto: {
            county: null,
            municipality: null,
            municipalitySection: null,
            address: "Attica, N. Ionia, Iolkou",
            addrNumberFrom: 8,
            addrNumberTo: 0,
            addrLetterFrom: null,
            addrLetterTo: null,
            addressSec: null,
            addrSecLetterFrom: null,
            addrSecLetterTo: null,
            addrSecNumberFrom: 0,
            addrSecNumberTo: 0,
            postalCode: "2"
        },
        realEstateEstimationValuesResDtos: [ ]
    },
]
```

I want the output to have only the properties, without the objects keys inside.
I'm using this function:

```
const flatten = o =>
  Object.keys(o).reduce(
    (obj, key) =>
      typeof o[key] === "object" && o[key] !== null
        ? { ...obj, ...flatten(o[key]) }
        : { ...obj, [key]: o[key] },
    {}
  );
```

It seems to work fine, but the result I'm getting here on my array of objects is this:

```
flatten(arr) = 
{
        addrLetterFrom: null
        addrLetterTo: null
        addrNumberFrom: 8
        addrNumberTo: 0
        addrSecLetterFrom: null
        addrSecLetterTo: null
        addrSecNumberFrom: 0
        addrSecNumberTo: 0
        address: "Attica, N. Ionia, Iolkou"
        addressSec: null
        assetId: "3"
        county: null
        kind: "Class01"
        municipality: null
        municipalitySection: null
        postalCode: null
        type: "Detached house"    
}
```

It is actually returning only the last object flattened. I want to return an array with both objects flattened. What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a sample *output* for good measure? You'll get an answer in no-time for this if you do :)

Comment: Your objects in your array seem to only have strings and numbers as values, but objects can also have objects and arrays as values. Would you like those flattened too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `flatten` function handles a single object, so you need to iterate the array with `Array.map()`, and apply your flatten function to each object:

```js
const arr = [{"realEstateBasicInfoResDto":{"type":"Detached house","kind":"Class01"},"assetId":"1","realEstateAddressInfoResDto":{"county":null,"municipality":null,"municipalitySection":null,"address":"Attica, N. Ionia, Iolkou","addrNumberFrom":8,"addrNumberTo":0,"addrLetterFrom":null,"addrLetterTo":null,"addressSec":null,"addrSecLetterFrom":null,"addrSecLetterTo":null,"addrSecNumberFrom":0,"addrSecNumberTo":0,"postalCode":"1"},"realEstateEstimationValuesResDtos":[]},{"realEstateBasicInfoResDto":{"type":"Detached house","kind":"Class01"},"assetId":"11","realEstateAddressInfoResDto":{"county":null,"municipality":null,"municipalitySection":null,"address":"Attica, N. Ionia, Iolkou","addrNumberFrom":8,"addrNumberTo":0,"addrLetterFrom":null,"addrLetterTo":null,"addressSec":null,"addrSecLetterFrom":null,"addrSecLetterTo":null,"addrSecNumberFrom":0,"addrSecNumberTo":0,"postalCode":"2"},"realEstateEstimationValuesResDtos":[]}];

const flatten = o =>
  Object.keys(o).reduce(
    (obj, key) =>
    typeof o[key] === "object" && o[key] !== null ?
    { ...obj,
      ...flatten(o[key])
    } :
    { ...obj,
      [key]: o[key]
    }, {}
  );
  
const result = arr.map(flatten);

console.log(result);
```